# using c3p0 connection pool with hibernate 3

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, connection-pooling

Technologies: JSF, Hibernate 3, eclipse. Glassfish server
My website works 100% locally but when I deployed it, it just closes the connection after a while.

I thought of using a connection pool to avoid this issue

I downloaded the jar file c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar and added it in java class path an added the following configs in hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate-c3p0-4.3.10.Final.jar

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

and it gives an error that a class named LogM is not found. might the jar file I used be a wrong one? or did I miss a step?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.log.MLog
```